# subprocess.run not function with pyinstaller

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I call to script fran_v2.py but when push de button the application is lock and create a new window of GUI, what can i do? fails when the program call to subprocess.run([fran_v2.py...

```
def GButton_154_command(self):
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

    aux = self.filenames.get()
    images = aux.split("\n")
    images.remove(images[len(images)-1])
    print("Estos son los archivos recibidos")
    print(images)

    for image in images:
        folder = image.replace(".jpg", "")
        folder = folder.replace("/", "\\") + "\\fran"
        file = image.replace("/", "\\")
        name_of_file = file.split("\\")
        length = len(name_of_file)
        name = name_of_file[length - 1]
        subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', folder], shell=True)
        subprocess.Popen(["copy", file, folder], shell=True)
        print(name)
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, "fran_v2.py", folder + "\\" + name], shell=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I developed this application with tkinter in Python, when you press the button call a script wich name is fran_v2.py and it's included in the project. The code of button is that appear in the post, in this code, there is a call script fran_v2.py with subprocess.run, all function well untill i generated the executable file with pyinstaller --onefile name_script.py then when you press the button  nothing ocurred, the window not respond and appear a new window of the application, would be help me someone? Very thanks

Comment: Is the problem I have correctly explained?

Comment: This seems to me a bit difficult to reproduce your problem, I would recommend you to read [How  to write a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the title you mention the threads module like this which could deduce that the problem can originate from there, so you should also check [docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) I hope it helps you